# activemq resource adapter in weblogic

Tags: xml, oracle, activemq-classic, weblogic12c, resource-adapter

I have deployed activemq resource adapter in weblogic. I need to restrict the number of connections to activemq.I have created a weblogic-ra.xml file and kept it inside meta-inf folder of resource adapter. It is still accepting n number of connections. what am I doing wrong?. Is there any other way to restrict the number of connections. Please help

Weblogic-ra.xml contents

javax.jms.ConnectionFactory 
            
               eis/activemq-ra_javax_jms_ConnectionFactory
               
                   
                     0 
                     0 
                     1
                     false
                     900

```
           </connection-properties> 
        </connection-instance> 

  </connection-definition-group> 
 <connection-definition-group>
     <connection-factory-interface>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</connection-factory-interface> 
     <connection-instance>
        <jndi-name>eis/activemq-ra_javax_jms_QueueConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
        <connection-properties> 
              <pool-params>
                    <initial-capacity>0</initial-capacity>
                    <max-capacity>0</max-capacity>
                    <capacity-increment>1</capacity-increment>
                    <shrinking-enabled>false</shrinking-enabled>
                    <shrink-frequency-seconds>900</shrink-frequency-seconds>
              </pool-params>


           </connection-properties>
     </connection-instance>
 </connection-definition-group>
 <connection-definition-group>
     <connection-factory-interface>javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory</connection-factory-interface> 
     <connection-instance>
        <jndi-name>eis/activemq-ra_javax_jms_TopicConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
        <connection-properties> 
              <pool-params>
                    <initial-capacity>0</initial-capacity>
                    <max-capacity>0</max-capacity>
                    <capacity-increment>1</capacity-increment>
                    <shrinking-enabled>false</shrinking-enabled>
                    <shrink-frequency-seconds>900</shrink-frequency-seconds>
              </pool-params>


           </connection-properties>
     </connection-instance>
 </connection-definition-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved!!!!

Ive added activemq jndi name to my code

Context context = new InitialContext();
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("eis/activemq-ra_javax_jms_ConnectionFactory");
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

Now my application communicates with resource adapter and  restricts the number of connections as per the weblogic-ra.xml file given above